# What does the k-value stand for in a KNN model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, k-nearest-neighbour

What is the k-value in a KNN classification model? Is K the number of Clusters?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Eva. I took the liberty of editing your question for clarity based on what I guessed you are really asking. Please make sure it still says what you want it to say.

Comment: K actually is the number of neighbours to be considered

Answer (score 13):

The $k$-nearest neighbours algorithm uses a very simple approach to perform classification. When tested with a new example, it looks through the training data and finds the $k$ training examples that are closest to the new example. It then assigns the most common class label (among those $k$ training examples) to the test example.

$k$ is therefore just the number of neighbors "voting" on the test example's class.

If $k=1$, then test examples are given the same label as the closest example in the training set. If $k=3$, the labels of the three closest classes are checked and the most common (i.e., occuring at least twice) label is assigned, and so on for larger $k$s.

When you build a $k$-nearest neighbor classifier, you choose the value of $k$. You  might have a specific value of $k$ in mind, or you could divide up your data and use something like cross-validation to test several values of $k$ in order to determine which works best for your data. For $n=1000$ cases, I would bet that the optimal $k$ is somewhere between 1 and 19, but you'd really have to try it to be sure.

Comment: What will be the K-value if my data contains 10000 records

Comment: That's entirely up to you. You can either choose a fixed $k$ (based on your experience or results with similar data) or use a procedure like cross-validation to determine which $k$ works best for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Knn does not use clusters per se, as opposed to k-means sorting.

Knn is a classification algorithm that classifies cases by copying the already-known classification of the *k* nearest neighbors, i.e. the k number of cases that are considered to be "nearest" when you convert the cases as points in a euclidean space.

K-means is a clustering algorithm that splits a dataset as to minimize the euclidean distance between each point and a central measure of its cluster.

Typically, Knn works this way:

1. You'll need a training set with cases that have already been categorized. The cases will become points in a euclidean space, so you'll want the values to have some kind of normalization so that they are on the same scale.
2. Take the first case in the data you want to categorize. Calculate the distance (usually, euclidean distance) between this case and every cases in the training set.
3. Select the *k* training cases that have the smallest distance and look at their classification. These are the *k* Nearest Neighbors, or kNN. According to the "if it quacks like a duck and walks like a duck it must be a duck" principle, if a majority of it's kNNs are classified as X, then the test case must also be a class X. So you just take the most popular classification of the *k* nearest points and you're done.
4. Do that for every other cases in your dataset.

So *k* could be described as a parameter that determines the "depth" of the algorithm (how many points will be considered in the classification). As suggested by Nadeem Inayat, a rule of thumb is to use the square root of the training set sample size as a starting point. However, the optimal value for *k* depends on the context: are you trying to minimize the total number of misclassified points? Or are some  misclassifications (e.g. false negative) considered to be worse than others?